# Moment.js, how to just change a format of a date without changing timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I want to change a format of a date and time string. But moment.js changes timezone to my system timezone (+3):

```
// This is a string:
"2013-09-20 23:59:59 +0100"

// I want to change it to this:
"20-09-2013 23:59:59 +0100"

// This is what I do and what I get. 1 hour is added by force:
moment("2013-09-20 23:59:59 +0100").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ")
"21-09-2013 01:59:59 +0300"
```

How to just change a format without changing timezone?

Answer (score 5):

See [moment issue #887](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/887), directly regarding this.  It may be easier in a future version, but the current workaround is as follows:

```
var input = "2013-09-20 23:59:59 +0100";
var m = moment(input).zone(input);
m.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ")
```

Answer (score 5):

In moment.js v-2.8.3:

```
var dateTime = "2014-12-09 13:59:59 +0930";
var parseDateTimeZone = moment.parseZone(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

[Doc-API](https://github.com/icambron/moment/commit/2e9286705e88faf842bca4d2221cc58c4c3ce929)